# How to format the Excel document created by POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working in an application where I am creating an Excel document using POI. The problem is, when generating the Excel without any data is fine, but when I am putting the data with it then the headers are going down. My code:

```
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = null;
            hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) largest);

            HSSFCell intervieweeName = rowhead.createCell(0);
            intervieweeName.setCellValue("Interviee Name");

            HSSFCell interviewTiming = rowhead.createCell(1);
            interviewTiming.setCellValue("Interview Timing");

    for (int large = 0; large < largest; large++) {

            int i=0;
            HSSFRow array1 = sheet.createRow((short)large);
            for ( i = i + large; i < interviewerNameList.size(); i++) { 
            HSSFCell tracker1 = array1.createCell(0);
            HSSFCell tracker2 = array1.createCell(1);

            tracker1.setCellValue(interviewerNameList.get(large));
            tracker2.setCellValue(interviewTimingToFrom1.get(large));

            }
            }
```

The problem is that the heading Interviee Name and Interview Timing are coming after the values.

Comment: @Gagravarr i did not understand can you point out and correct my mistake??

Comment: Sorry, re-read it now. Why are you putting the header row at the end, on (row=largest)? Why not put them in the first row (0) and put your values in subsequent (1+) rows?

Comment: @Gagravarr please edit my code it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're writing the header into the last row

```
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) largest);
...
for (int large = 0; large < largest; large++) {
    HSSFRow array1 = sheet.createRow((short)large);
```

That puts the header at the end, and loops from 0 to that to create the data rows

Change it instead to be something like:

```
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);
...
for (int large = 0; large < largest; large++) {
    HSSFRow array1 = sheet.createRow(large+1);
```

That way, the `large` variable remains unchanged for your data lookup, but you populate things in row 1 onwards